# Do subtle and causal bodies have sense organs like ears, eyes, etc..?

Tags: atma, afterlife, naraka, indriyas

As per my understanding, after death if I go to hell then my subtle and causal bodies will suffer and not my Atma.

Death causes the cessation of gross body or the Annamaya kosha and the Pranamaya Kosha. However  Manomaya Kosha, Vignanamaya Kosha and Anandamaya Kosha remain along with the Atma.

My questions are :

Do subtle and causal bodies have sense organs like ear, eyes, nose etc..?

If subtle and causal bodies do not have them how do these bodies suffer in hell?
(In order to suffer one must have gross six sense media which is lost after death.)

Comment: subtle bodies gets different bodies in different hell. They are called "yatana shareera"

Comment: @sysinit Do subtle bodies get different bodies in heaven ? If yes what are they called?

Comment: In every loka , one needs to get a body. Merely with subtle body , one cant do much . In heaven one should get bhoga shareera,pitru sharira in pitru loka , yatana shareera in hell

Comment: In dream we experiences such things without senses of gross body. Similarly I think one may experience with subtle body or say AntahKarana.

Comment: Just remember , kamadeva was burned into ashes by shiva. His divine body was destroyed. But his athman is unaffected by shiva's wrath. He had to wait multiple yugas , before he got reincarnated as pradyumna , where he got a human body.